# Is J2ME worth learning

Tags: java, java-me, mobile

I want to get into some mobile development. I studied a tiny bit of J2ME way back in the day and it wasn't too bad. But now with newer technologies like Android and so forth I ask myself if it is worth my while to (re)learn and invest in J2ME as there is this perception that it is 'old' and 'clunky', yet it's what still runs on most mobile phones. What do you all think? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know, but this Google Trends comparison suggests that Android is far more significant:

http://www.google.com/trends?q=java+mobile,+android&ctab=0&geo=all&date=ytd&sort=0

You might also be interested in this:

[J2ME VS Android VS iPhone VS Symbian VS Windows CE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414288/j2me-vs-android-vs-iphone-vs-symbian-vs-windows-ce)

Not an exact duplicate, but close...

Answer (score 0):

It's not difficult if you already know Java so why not?  Everyone focuses on consumer stuff like smart phones, but it's used in a lot of embedded systems, so it might pop up in a project.