# Read/Write Kovio NFC tags using Farpointe Data Reader

Tags: java-me, nfc, ndef

We have bought a `KOVIO 2K NFC` tags, alongwith that we got `Farpointe Data reader`. We are able to read write these tags using Nexus. However, we are building an `API` where we want `to write` to these `tags` through Server code without any mobile phone API. Is there any Java API which supports writing to NFC tags?

Is there any software/SDK to read the data using Farpointe Data Reader?

Answer (score 2):

Kovio 2K NFC tags can be configured as [NFC Forum Type 2 Tags](http://www.nfc-forum.org/specs/spec_list/). There is a Java ME API that supports NFC Forum tags: [JSR 257](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=257). (I wonder how relevant this API still is, though, see also the answers to this question: [Java NFC (JSR 257)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886868/java-nfc-jsr-257).)
I am not familiar with the Farpointe Data Reader, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you know if we can use contactless communication API(J2ME) in normal Java code

Comment: I am not a Java expert. So far, I have seen JSR 257 only on some older NFC mobile phones (mostly Nokia).