# Which one is better in which area Symbian, android and bada?

Tags: android, symbian, mobile-phones, bada

Although all mobile OS are good but still there must be a comparison based on different area, so i want to know the difference between these operating system.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, bada is only a framework not an OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many things to take into consideration when comparing mobile OS.

As this is a developer list, I guess you are interested in development related comparisons?

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_application_development
- [How does iPhone development compare to Symbian development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132425/how-does-iphone-development-compare-to-symbian-development)

This is important for your marketing & if you develop & sell apps:

- http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/63772.aspx